# Cross compile for ARM using Maven NAR Plugin

Tags: c++, maven, arm, cross-compiling, maven-nar-plugin

I am trying to build an C++ application for both x86/amd64 and ARM with the Maven NAR plugin on Debian/Ubuntu. I've troubles to set up a correct profile for the ARM cross-compile build with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc.

The profile snippet from my pom.xml looks like this:

```
        <profile>
        <id>arm-linux-cross</id>
        <properties>
            <debug.option>true</debug.option>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <arch>arm</arch>
                        <cpp>
                            <name>arm-linux-gnueabi-g++</name>
                            <options>
                                <option>-march=armv5</option>
                            </options>
                        </cpp>
                        <linker>
                            <name>arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc</name>
                            <sysLibs>
                                <sysLib>
                                    <name>stdc++</name>
                                </sysLib>
                                ...
                            </sysLibs>
                        </linker>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Building that profile with `mvn compile -P arm-linux-cross' does not work:

```
[INFO] Using AOL: amd64-Linux-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.464s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Feb 13 11:00:05 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/147M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.maven-nar:nar-maven-plugin:3.0.0:nar-validate (default-nar-validate) on project sirka-model: Cannot find version number for linker 'arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc' -> [Help 1]
```

Obviously the AOL used here is not available so Maven does not recognize the compiler/linker. 
But how can I add the required AOL? 
Or is there another way to cross-compile for ARM with Maven?

Comment: Have you checked the most recent version of [nar-maven-plugin](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.github.maven-nar|nar-maven-plugin|3.2.2|maven-plugin) ?

Comment: There's no accepted answer on this issue--how did you end up resolving it?

Comment: @mbroshi I didn't ;-) I simply stopped trying...

Answer (score 3):

Someone recently [added basic ARM support to the NAR plugin](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/pull/89). But the AOL is just `arm-Linux-gcc`—I don't know where your `gnueabi` above is coming from.

If the NAR plugin's [standard ARM settings](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/blob/nar-maven-plugin-3.2.2/src/main/resources/com/github/maven_nar/aol.properties#L562-L600) do not work for you, you can try using your own variation. [Here is an example project](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/tree/nar-maven-plugin-3.2.2/src/it/it0023-local-aol-properties) that defines its own custom AOL properties.